# How to Change the Microsoft Office 2007 icons?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

How do I change the icons for Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc?

Already went to Properties > Customize, but the change icon is pretty much not optional

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create your OWN shortcuts to the executable files (e.g. `c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\winword.exe`) and then change the icons as you like.

Your problem is probably related to a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/67649/different-types-of-shortcuts) I posted a while ago.

The difference:

[image]

Comment: Actually, they are shortcuts, I forgot to mention that

^^

Comment: i know they're shortcuts. yet it actually doesn't point to winword.exe but to a stub executable called wordicon.exe

Comment: you're more than welcome.